# How do I get the current option values into an array?

Tags: javascript, html-select

Suppose I have a list:

```
    <select>
  <option value="Horse">Horse</option>
  <option value="Bird">Bird</option>
  <option value="Dogs">Dogs</option>
  <option value="Cats">Cats</option>
</select>
```

I know how to grab the values of each option by looping through. My problem is I have code that changes the default values to something if certain conditions are met but if the conditions are not met I need to revert back to the DEFAULT values. I need to get the default values into an array so I can use them to revert back if the conditions are not met...etc. I need pure javascript no frameworks.

So for example if I change `<option value="Horse">Horse</option>`to `<option value="Train">Train</option>`I need to be able to store `<option value="Horse">Horse</option>` BEFORE it gets changed the same way you can get the default value for an input field to revert back to it if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution and that is to get the values on page load and make sure your script is before the closing body tag.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code:

```js
var options = document.querySelectorAll("option");
var optionsArray = Array.prototype.map.call(options, function(x) {
  return x.value;
});
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="Horse">Horse</option>
  <option value="Bird">Bird</option>
  <option value="Dogs">Dogs</option>
  <option value="Cats">Cats</option>
</select>
```